# change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy in views of the webform

Tags: views

I have created the fields for the view extracte from a webform. It is working perfectly. But when i try to extract the date field it just get the date it yyyy/mm/dd format. Now I searched alot but no where i could find easy steps to convert the date format of this field to dd/mm/yyyy. 
Please explain in easy steps how to convert my field to my required date format.

Answer (score 1):

Visit **admin/settings/date-time/formats** in you instance & add a custom date format. See [PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the options which you can.

Use your created date format to show the field value wherever you want like views.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this for future devs who stumble upon this. For me in the Webform Submission Data field, choosing "Number" and "Plain Text" resulted in dd/mm/yyyy format